# Getting java exception error while reading xml file

Tags: xml, matlab, xml-parsing

I'm trying to read in the xml file provided for the IAM database in order to structure the database. I am using Matlab to read these files in and am using `xmlread`.

The xml files are well over 1500 and almost all of them are giving the same error:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/iamdb/form-metadata.dtd

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
```

Here is one of the xml files I am trying to read in: http://pastebin.com/TtQz4ZCV

The not found link at the top is to a 404 page, so it no longer exists and they forgot to fix it.

Is my only option now to manually remove this line from all xml files? or is there an easy fix to read this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable external DTD loading for the parser. To accomplish this, you can create a custom [`DocumentBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) object, [disable the external DTD loading](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#nonvalidating.load-external-dtd), and pass this as the second input to `xmlread`.

From the hidden `xmlread` documentation (visible if you open the file with `edit xmlread`):

```matlab
% Advanced use:
%   Note that FILENAME can also be an InputSource, File, or InputStream object
%   DOMNODE = XMLREAD(FILENAME,...,P,...) where P is a DocumentBuilder object
%   DOMNODE = XMLREAD(FILENAME,...,'-validating',...) will create a validating
%             parser if one was not provided.
%   DOMNODE = XMLREAD(FILENAME,...,ER,...) where ER is an EntityResolver will
%             will set the EntityResolver before parsing
%   DOMNODE = XMLREAD(FILENAME,...,EH,...) where EH is an ErrorHandler will
%             will set the ErrorHandler before parsing
%   [DOMNODE,P] = XMLREAD(FILENAME,...) will return a parser suitable for passing
%             back to XMLREAD for future parses.
%
```

So this ends up looking something like this:

```matlab
% Create the DocumentBuilder
builder = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance;

% Disable validation
builder.setFeature('http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd', false);

% Read your file
xml = xmlread(filename, builder);
```

Keep in mind that this *could* potentially result in your file being parsed incorrectly.

**Update**

So looking into this a little closer, once we get past the DTD validation failing, the FEX `xml2struct` doesn't handle the `DOCTYPE` entry in the XML correctly and tries to process it just like a normal node. You could modify the source of `xml2struct` to detect this internally:

```
if node.getNodeType == node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE
```

However, it would probably be easier to just remove all the `DOCTYPE`s for all of your XML files. The following script should be able to do this.

```
folder = 'directory/where/all/files/live';

files = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.xml'));

for k = 1:numel(files)
    filename = fullfile(folder, files(k).name);
    fid = fopen(filename, 'rt');
    content = fread(fid, '*char')';
    fclose(fid);

    newcontent = regexprep(content, '\n\s*?<!DOCTYPE.*?(?=\n)', '');

    fout = fopen(filename, 'wt');
    fwrite(fout, newcontent);
    fclose(fout);
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this now opens the file. But I am getting another error while getting data from one of the child nodes. I'm using ``getNodeData``. This gives an error of ``Undefined function 'toCharArray' for input arguments of type 'double'.`` But when I edit my xml file and remove the dtd link at line 3. And not use the builder I am able to open the file and get the data from the xml file. You did mention that the builder may parse my file incorrectly. Is that the reason for the error?

Comment: @StuckInPhD I'll look into it. But in the meantime what you can do is delete that line from *one* file, load it and store the second output `P` above. Then pass this in place of `builder` to try to read another file

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am now getting the initial java exception error again. I read in the edited xml file with the second output ``p``, and then used the ``p`` in place of ``builder`` as the second argument when reading in the unedited xml file.

Comment: @StuckInPhD Can you link to the actual code you're trying to run?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in my first post. I am using the ``xml2struct`` script that converts the ``DOM``file returned to a struct. It works on the edited file without the link but gives errors on the non edited file with``builder``. http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct

Comment: @StuckInPhD Turns out it's a bug in `xml2struct`. I have posted code to just remove all those `<!DOCTYPE>` entries